# holding value in dropdown after submitting or refreshing

Tags: php, mysqli, dropdown, explode

```
<?php
  $sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from calls where eid='$aid'")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
  while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
  {
    ?><select name='city'>
        <option value="">Select City</option>
    <?php   
    $c=explode(',', $row2['city']);
    foreach ($c as $c1) 
    {
     ?>
     <option value='$c1'  <?php if(isset($_POST['search']) || isset($_POST['next'])|| isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
         if(($c==$c1))
          { echo 'Selected';} 
        }?>><?php echo $c1;?></option>"

  <?php }
    echo"</select>";
  }
    ?>
```

calls table city is stored as comma separated array. I have successfully get it into drop-down box. Now I want that whenever I submit or page refresh it holds se selected drop-down value.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: This might be helpful to you to make your code more readable: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `isset($_POST["city"]) &&  $_POST["city"] == $city`

```
foreach ($cities as $city) 
{
  $selection = (isset($_POST["city"]) &&  $_POST["city"] == $city  ? 'selected':''  );
  echo ' <option value="'.$city.'" '.$selection.' >'.$city.'</option>';
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to compare the value of `$c1` against its previous value returned by the form submit, after checking that this execution is the result of the form being posted.

```
<?php

$sql = "select * from calls where eid=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $aid)
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<select name='city'>
    <option value="">Select City</option>
<?php   
    $c=explode(',', $row2['city']);
    foreach ($c as $c1) {
        $sel = '';   // init value 
        if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $c1 == $_POST['city'] ) {
            $sel = "selected='selected'";
        }

        echo "<option $sel value='$c1' >$c1</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

Comment: It seems You are mixing mysqli and PDO

Comment: @IndraKumarS Thanks, it was actually worse than that, I was confusing everything :)

Comment: There is no such method `fetch_assoc()` in prepared stmt.